# Vba changing directory to save

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to save a file in a directory whose name changes according to the name of the Previous Month. Here is the code:

```
name_month = MonthName(Month(Date) - 1) 

Set Newbook = Workbooks.Add
    With Newbook
.Title = "TESO1"
.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\ee31264\Desktop\Mensile Automat\name_month \send\TESO1.xlsx"
End With

Newbook.Close
```

unfortunately the name_month i wrote VBA doesn't read what I mean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you need to tell Excel if what you say to it should be read as a variable or as string of text. Using "" says it is string of text and should not be evaluated.

Use this:

```
Filename:="C:\Users\ee31264\Desktop\Mensile Automat\" & name_month & "\send\TESO1.xlsx"
```

Also remember that in newer versions of Excel you also have to specify file format by using `FileFormat:=51` (xlsx, use 52 for xlsm).